# Add plugin by SVN. Current version problem

Tags: plugins, svn

i need add new version of plugin.

And i have one problem! On my plugin link http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-facebook-comments/ i steel see current version 0.7.6 but i add 0.7.7 Look on this skrin http://szymoon.nazwa.pl/images/verssionscrin.jpg I don't now why but version 0.7.7 is not current version why?

Comment: You have still `Version: 0.7.6` as plugin version in your tag `0.7.7`.

Comment: I don't understand....

Comment: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/simple-facebook-comments/tags/0.7.7/simple-facebook-comments.php says `Version: 0.7.6`

Comment: ok, i don't change version in my php file that was wrong. Saw if must change in readme.txt and php plugin file then cummit, taged and update. That all. Sory for trobule and thx for help.